# How can I create a function that waits until an expression is true, then returns part of it

Tags: python

I'd like to build a generic "waiter" function that will take two pieces of input, evaluate them over and over until the combined expression evaluates as True, and then return the value of the first piece of input. But I don't even know what this kind of thing is called, so I'm having a hard time searching for it.

I have an existing function that does some of this, but I want to extend it so that the single lambda `expression` is broken into two parts, and the value of the first is returned.

Here's my existing code:

```
def wait_until(expression, timeout=30, period=10, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
    """Wait until expression is true"""
    end_time = time.time() + timeout
    while time.time() < end_time:
        try:
            if expression(*args, **kwargs):
                log.debug("That's the one!")
                return
            else:
                log.debug("That's not the one")
        except Exception as e:
            log.debug(f"Exception caught and ignored while executing the predicate: {e}")
        time.sleep(period)
    log.error("Timed out")
    raise TimeoutError(f"Timed out waiting {timeout} seconds")
```

I can use the function like this:

```
>>> wait_until(lambda: random.randint(0, 9) % 2 == 0)
```

And here's the behavior of the new wait_until function I'd like to have. I want it to return the random number that's divisible by 2 once it finds one, to use this same example.

I'm still pretty new to Python so I don't know the best approach for this given the features the language gives. I'm using 3.7, BTW.

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> wait_until(randint(0, 9), "% 2 == 0")
4
>>> wait_until(randint(0, 9), "== 10", Timeout=30)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TimeoutError: input expression was not "== 10" in less than 30 seconds
```

The second argument doesn't have to be a string necessarily. The main point is that the value returned by the first argument is compared to the second argument to determine truth. And the first argument is re-evaluated each time, since its value is expected to change.

Comment: In the conditional statement where you'd return the first value, you could start a new thread to run the same function to evaluate the second expression. But I'm not sure how robust that solution would be.

Comment: Your lambda doesn't take any input, so there's no way to return the input that caused it to be true.

Comment: @PyNoob Oh boy, tackling Python threading just for this seems like overkill. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split your `expression` argument into two arguments: one function that generates values, another that tests the value. Then you call the generator, pass the result to the tester, and if it succeeds you return the value.

```
def wait_until(generator, tester, timeout = 30, period = 10, *args, **kwargs):
    end_time = time.time() + timeout
    while time.time() < end_time:
        try:
            val = generator(*args, **kwargs)
            if tester(val):
                log.debug("That's the one!")
                return val
            else:
                log.debug("That's not the one")
        except Exception as e:
            log.debug(f"Exception caught and ignored while executing the predicate: {e}")
        time.sleep(period)
    log.error("Timed out")
    raise TimeoutError(f"Timed out waiting {timeout} seconds")

print(wait_until(lambda: random.randint(0, 9), lambda x: x % 2 == 0))
```

Comment: Just pay attention that you will have to change your call from `wait_until(randint(0, 9), "% 2 == 0")` to `wait_until(lambda: randint(0, 9), lambda x: x % 2 == 0)`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. After I posted the question I thought of a complication that this approach already covers. That was to do something like `lambda: len(some_function()) > 5` but returning the value of some_function() and not the length of the value of some_function().